# Is there a default ftp server in Debian Wheezy default installation?

Tags: debian, ftp

I just finished installing a test web server with Debian Wheezy, apache and phpPgAdmin. I don't know if the default installation includes the ftp server.

- How can I check if one is installed?
- What do I need to do to start it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can offer advice on specific problems, but a general question like this is too broard to be given a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different FTP servers packaged within Debian, which you can see via:

```
apt-cache search ftp-server
```

One of the most popular servers around is proftpd, and that can be installed upon Debian systems with:

```
apt-get install proftpd
```

Once downloaded debconf will ask if you wish to run the server via inetd, or in a standalone fashion. In general you want the latter option.

After the installation the server will be running, and will grant access to all user accounts upon the host.

If you wish to stop the server prior to more configuration you can do so with:

```
/etc/init.d/proftpd stop
```

The configuration of proftpd is conducted via the configuration file of `/etc/proftpd.conf`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question and found the answer by running Synaptic Package Manager and searching for 'ftp'.

In my case it wasn't proftp, it was openssh-sftp-server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
apt-get install proftpd
```